# pydeck icon layer - are folium-style clustered icons possible?

Tags: python, deck.gl, pydeck

My question: is it possible to do folium-style icon clustering using pydeck?

I'm making map visualizations for a dataset in which we've made measurements at a number of locations, returning to some locations many times across the past five years.  I've mapped the measurement locations using folium's MarkerClusters.  Markers cluster when the map is zoomed out:

[image: zoomed out cluster]

And then resolve to individual measurements upon zooming in:

[image]

I've been playing around with implementing my visualizations using pydeck.  The [deck.gl documentation](https://deck.gl/examples/icon-layer/) suggests that some degree of clustering is possible, but (1) I don't see how to implement that example, which uses javascript, using pydeck and more importantly (2) it seems the icons stack on top of one another at some zoom level when some icons share the same location.

Is this kind of thing doable using pydeck?